# Update JSON Array in Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift5, swifty-json

I have a JSON array fetching from url and convert using SwiftyJSON. Now i want to update some value of JSON Array for some functionality.

My JSON is like

```
[
    {
      "id" : 48845152,
      "studentPhotoTakenCount" : 0,
      "updatedAt" : null,
      "isAttendedToday: false
    },
 {     "id" : 48845153,
      "studentPhotoTakenCount" : 0,
      "updatedAt" : null,
      "isAttendedToday: false
    },
  
  ]
```

After some action i want to update my JSON Array by filtering id.
Like if i have id = 48845152 then only update

```
{
      "id" : 48845152,
      "studentPhotoTakenCount" : 0,
      "updatedAt" : null,
      "isAttendedToday: false
    }
```

and finally merge with my JSON Array. So the final result should be

```
[
    {
      "id" : 48845152,
      "studentPhotoTakenCount" : 0,
      "updatedAt" : null,
      "isAttendedToday: false
    },
 {     "id" : 48845153,
      "studentPhotoTakenCount" : 0,
      "updatedAt" : null,
      "isAttendedToday: false
    },

  ]
```

My code is like that.

```
self.studentList.forEach {
                        if let id = $0["id"].int {
                            if id == _studentId {
                                $0["isAttendedToday"] =  true
                                self.filteredStudentList.append($0)
                            }
                            else {
                                self.filteredStudentList.append($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Here `self.studentList` is my JSON. But i get the error saying that

> Cannot assign through subscript: '$0' is immutable

Please someOne help me to find out what getting wrong here.

Comment: $0["isAttendedToday"] =  true, this line causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this syntax you cannot modify the source array, but you could modify the destination array

```
self.studentList.forEach {
    self.filteredStudentList.append($0)
    if let id = $0["id"].int, id == _studentId {
       let lastIndex = self.filteredStudentList.count - 1
       self.filteredStudentList[lastIndex]["isAttendedToday"] = true
    }
}
```

If the source array is supposed to be modified you have to use this

```
for (index, item) in self.studentList.enumerated() {
    self.filteredStudentList.append(item)
    if let id = item["id"].int, id == _studentId {
       self.studentList[index]["isAttendedToday"] = true
    }
}
```

In both cases due to value type semantics you have to modify the arrays directly.

PS:

In Swift 5 there is no reason anymore to use `SwiftyJSON`. `Codable` is more versatile, more efficient and built-in.

Comment: your first solution got some error saying 'Cannot assign to property: 'last' is a get-only property'. But second method is working. thank you

Comment: Please see the edit and be aware that both suggestions do different things.

Comment: thank you very much but can you describe why 'Cannot assign through subscript: '$0' is immutable' error occured??

Comment: `$0` represents the current item in the loop. It's a copy and treated as `let` constant, therefore immutable.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually i am new to swift and learning with working